# Python: Is there a better way to remove a data range from a DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am working under Python `2.5` and pandas version `0.9.0` and need to remove a range of dates from a DataFrame.
I performed this with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime(2009,06,01,10,0)
date2 =  datetime.datetime(2009,06,02,05,00)
dates = pd.date_range(start=date1,end=date2,freq="30min")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(dates), 1)*1500, index=dates, columns=['Power'])

date3 = datetime.datetime(2009,06,01,16,0)
date4 = datetime.datetime(2009,06,01,23,0)
df1 = df[df.index <= date3]
df2 = df[df.index >= date4]
df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Is there a better way to get the same results?

I was expecting something like this would work:

```
df_new2 = df[df.index <= date3 | df.index >= date4]
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'datetime.datetime' and 'DatetimeIndex'
```

Comment: Put parentheses around each condition: df_new2 = df[(df.index <= date3) | (df.index >= date4)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that python does not know how to apply the boolean operations. Do this:

```
df_new2 = df[(df.index <= date3) | (df.index >= date4)]
```